# why Q.15 multiplication isn't working

Tags: c, printf, signal-processing, fixed-point

Refering [Notation for fixed point representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422557/notation-for-fixed-point-representation/22422976#22422976) i have tried following, but i am totally confused.

```
int q = 1<<15;
printf("(sys3.b0 * q) = %hx \n",((0.2929 * q)));
```

output is

```
((0.2929 * q)) = cc60
```

I expect to see 257d because from calculator, `0.2929 * 32768 in hex = 257d`

What is the problem in using this Q.15 format, or is this just because of not properly printing

---

### EDIT

Guys, actually i've never thought of it.

My actual code tries to print two values. I thought 2nd value printing is the problem. After comments of @Soren i copied his code and is working. Then i removed 1st value from printf, my code also worked. So i repost the printf statement

```
printf("(sys3.b0 * q) = %X \t((0.2929 * q)) = %X\n",(sys3.b0 * q),(unsigned)((0.2929 * q)));
printf("(sys3.b0 * q) = %X \n",((unsigned)(0.2929 * q)));
```

where the second line is as suggested by Seron.

`The value of sys3.b0 = 0.0000000001295`

Now the output is

```
(sys3.b0 * q) = 4DB173CF        ((0.2929 * q)) = 3ED1CC60
(sys3.b0 * q) = 257D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) the result of:

```
0.2929 * q
```

is a double but you are telling `printf` it is a unsigned short. If you cast the result to *unsigned short* you will get the result you expect (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/SBVV9570)*):

```
printf("(sys3.b0 * q) = %hx \n",(unsigned short)(0.2929 * q));
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Having warning turned on or up should have indicated that this was a problem, both `gcc` and `clang` give similar errros:

> warning: format '%hx' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]

Although apparently Visual Studio does not.

Comment: i m in MS VC++ environment, and all warnings are up. typecasting still results same output

Comment: @nmxprime I added a live example with this code working correctly in visual studio.

Comment: @nmxprime still undefined behavior change `(sys3.b0 * q)` to `(unsigned)(sys3.b0 * q)`

Comment: Thanks! Fine, but anuy hint on this unusual behaviour? might be windows's way of doing? Now i dnt have linux pc to test it with gcc

Comment: @nmxprime you can use both `gcc` and `clang` through one of the many [online compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator) available. Undefined behavior means that the behavior is unpredictable when you specify `%X` but pass in a `double` most likely printf is taking garbage values from the stack or maybe registers since `double` will usually be larger than `unsigned`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Accepting your answer so that this thread may closed!!

Answer (score 0):

The format string expects a type different from the one you're actually giving it. My compiler says:

> foo.c:5:33: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]

So you need a cast to convert `0.2929 * q` from a `double` to an `unsigned int`. Like this:

```
int main() {
    int q = 1<<15;
    printf("(sys3.b0 * q) = %X \n",((unsigned)(0.2929 * q)));
}
```

EDIT: When you feed `printf` an argument of the wrong type, it'll read only as many bytes as the type it *thought* it was getting. In your case:

```
printf("(sys3.b0 * q) = %X \t((0.2929 * q)) = %X\n",
       (sys3.b0 * q),
       (unsigned)((0.2929 * q)))
```

The format string says to expect two `unsigned int`, that is, two times 4 bytes*. But you gave it a `double` and an `unsigned int`, which are respectively 8 and 4 bytes*.  `printf` just reads 4 bytes for each `%X`, so effectively it reads the 8-result of `sys3.b0 * q`, thinking those 8 bytes are two integers, which it then prints.

Comment: `(unsigned)((0.2929 * q))` still gives the same result. i am using MS VC++

Comment: changing `%hx` to `%x` gives `3ed1cc60`

Comment: Weird. Maybe try copying my program above, to make sure there isn't some typo?

Comment: your program works!! After testing i found more weird thing! Let me edit the question accordingly